# write a program that takes program names as its command line arguments

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do: Write a program that will take a series program names as its command line arguments.  Your goal is to make sure that these programs are always executing.  So, if they die, your program will restart them. This is the code I have, but the issue is that it is not starting all programs at once, so if the first one starts and does not terminate, you are not waiting forever. How can I fix my code?

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (string s in args) 
            {
                Process program = new Process();

                program.StartInfo.FileName = s;
                program.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                program.Start();
                program.WaitForExit();
                Properties.Settings.Default.IsRestarting = true;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                Application.Restart();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably need a separate thread for each program.

Comment: how would i fix the code?

Comment: As @RBarryYoung pointed out, an approach could be to launch a thread for each command line argument.  Each thread would launch their program, and wait for it to stop - and launch it again, and again, etc (to satisfy the requirement that each program keeps running).

Comment: What versions of .net and Visual Studio?

Comment: Both are 2013 versions

Comment: 2013 isn't a version of .Net

Comment: In the future please format your code.  I have done this for you this time as a courtesy.